# Can I transform this region into one bounded by two rays?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to map the region V = {$z \in C$ : |z| > 1, Im(z) < 0} onto the unit disc.

I was thinking of starting off by transforming it using the mobius transformation $\frac{z-1}{z+1}$ to map it to a region bounded by two rays, but for this to work $V$ would have to be bounded by the unit cicrle and the real axis, which I'm not sure it true.

Comment: first square, then take reciprocal, giving total $\frac1{z^2}$. So, do you want to map your region onto the unit disc, or onto a region bounded by two rays ... which of the two options? It is not clear which question to answer

Comment: The ultimate goal is to map it to the unit disc, but I thought a first step that would potentially lead me there is to map it to a region bounded by two rays, because I know how to proceed from there.